# I need to understand the basic compilation command for complication and deployment, what are its functionalities and how do it works?

Tags: magento2, command, m2e

Upgrade extension files => setup:upgrade
Deployment static content => setup:static-content:deploy
Generate Classes => setup:di:compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.`setup:upgrade` use for :

= Upgrades the Magento application, DB data, and schema

2. `setup:static-content:deploy` use for

= Generate the static file like images and CSS generated from LESS.

3. `setup:di:compile` use for :

= Application code generation (factories, proxies, Plugins, and so on)

For more information you can check this one :
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-compiler.html

Comment: Thank you dear friend

Comment: If answer help then mark as solution, so it will help other in community as well.